# Setting up User accounts on a new IMac such that all users can access the same basic file system

Tags: macos, user-accounts

I am in the process of setting up a new iMac and would like a suggestion or two on the above.

1) My Account would be admin. (this would also be the dev environment)
2) A Guest account for the whole family's general use.
3) A Standard account for my kid.

I will probably migrate all of my important family files from our old windows system to a linux server and access them through a private network as needed.

I would like to set up the system so most of the pictures, music, movies and general, non secure documents live on the Family account, however, if I am in the admin account, or my daughter is logged into her account, we access any or all of the files without moving to the Family user.

I was thinking maybe symlinks in and out of the shared folder but there is probably a more straight forward way.

Thanks

Comment: Under OS X 10.8 (I think, it's been a while), there were issues trying to mount an SMB fileshare (like the Linux server) from more than one account at a time.  For me (YMMV), if I mounted the share first, it would show up as say `/Volmues/Family`.  The next person who mounted it would get `/Volumes/Family1`, etc.  The 2nd user could see my mount under `/Volumes/Family/`, but could not access it.  If you're using something like iTunes or iPhoto, where the path to your files is important, this really messes things up, since the path changes depending on who mounted the share first.

Comment: I'd recommend using the "Shared" folder on the Mac (`/Users/Shared`, I think), if you have enough storage inside the Mac itself.